# PHP while loop, table row

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I'm trying to loop through a database and output data into a div, if there are 3 divs horizontally across it will the start a new `tr` until it reaches another 3 etc. It is currently outputted like :

```
[] [] []
[]
[] []
```

Currently I have it working when it reaches 3 it starts a new row, but I don't know how I can only echo a new `tr` once? As it creates a new table row each time.

```
echo '<table><tr>';  

while ($result) 
{
    $i ++;
    if ($i&3)
    {
      echo '<td>
         <div>Row Data</div>
       </td>'; 
    }

    else
    {       
      echo '<tr>
        <td>
          <div>Row Data</div>
        </td></tr>';
   }
}  
echo '</tr></table>';
```

The `$result` variable is the recordset from my SQL query, everything works fine I just don't know how to only create a new table row once?

Comment: where do you close the first tr that you open? The one near the table declaration.

Comment: Sorry missed that bit of code, added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reset your $i variable to 1 when you hit 3...

```
$i = 0;
echo '<table><tr>';  

while ($result) 
{

    if ($i<=2)
    {
      echo '<td>
         <div>Row Data</div>
       </td>'; 
    }

    else
    {       
      echo '</tr><tr>';
      echo '<td><div>Row Data</div></td>'; 
      $i = 0;
   }
    $i ++;

}  
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Or something like this...

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<table><tr>';
$i = 0;
while ($result) {
   if ($i > 2) {
      echo '</tr><tr>';
      $i = 0;
   }
   echo '<td></td>';
   $i++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a slightly slip of logic in your code. You want to break the line when 3 `<td>` have been added. currently you add a `<td>` in any case. Your counting is not working anymore.

Also I don't think bitwise operation is what you want. 
If you want 3 td's all the time, you will not accomplish that with &3. for example 3$3 is true, but 6&3 is not true. 7&3 is true. 11&3 is true. then 15&3 is true. You can either reset $i or you can use the % operator.

Answer (score 0):

Or with modulo:

```
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
      echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
```

so you wouldnt have to reset the $i.

Answer (score 0):

```
else
{       
  echo '<tr>
    <td>
      <div>Row Data</div>
    </td></tr>';
}
```

should read:

```
else
{       
  echo '</tr><tr>
    <td>
      <div>Row Data</div>
    </td>';
}
```